# AJAX request not working, 'Unexpected string in JSON'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make the below AJAX call but it fails every time.

```
var getServerUrl = function(){
    $.ajax({
        'url': 'config.json',
        'contentType' : 'application/json',
        'async': false,
        success: function(response) {
            if (!response.errorCode) {
                serverURL = response.serverUrl;
                getAccessToken();
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

The error logged in the console shows:

> Unexpected string in JSON at position 1810.

Comment: 1) Remove `async: false` 2) please show us the response text coming back from the request

Comment: Are you sure the error message isn't coming from `JSON.parse(error)` itself? Why are you trying to parse the error message anyway?

Comment: What do you get with `console.log(error);` ?

Comment: @JJJ : after removing JSON.parse(error), i still get the same error,
Unexpected string in JSON at position 1810.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I did try with async:true as well, though my scenario wants the request to flow synchronusly, despite the flaws of sync.

Comment: The error message means that the JSON you're receiving from the server is invalid. Specifically, the 1810th character. Take the response and copy-paste it into a validator.

Comment: @JJJ I am getting empty response.

Comment: If that error is coming from the server, shouldn't you be fixing the server-side code instead?

Comment: @TechHunger you should use async code. There's no excuse for using sync, unless running the request in `onbeforeunload`

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```js
var getServerUrl = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'config.json',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if (!response.errorCode) {
                serverURL = response.serverUrl;
                getAccessToken();
            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, error) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(error));
        }
    });
}
```

```html
try this..
```

Comment: Quoted or unquoted keys have nothing to do with the error OP is experiencing.